# Is there a way to prevent my Science ship from coming home after getting kicked out of a system?

Tags: stellaris

I'm early in my first game of *Stellaris* and I just made contact with my first alien race. This resulted in my science ship in their system immediately being kicked out of it. It used to be in the system I had circled in Red, which fell within the other race's control.

[image]

However, it then decided that to get home, it would follow the path in white,which involves jumping through a ton of systems (none of which I've yet explored) before finally getting home. All of these systems it is passing through seem to be outside of the area of control we're getting kicked out of.

Instead of flying home, I'd like it to actually continue its survey operations in these new systems. However, I can't seem to cancel its return trip home. I've tried clicking on the "Stop" option, but that didn't cancel anything. I've tried telling it to survey the system with the red arrow pointing to it (which it was in at the time I told it to do that), but it simply left, and as you can see in the image, it seems to be queued up to first go all the way home, and then come back out to that system.

Is there any way to prevent this ship from wasting a ton of time by going home first?

Comment: I think, this could be the exile mechanic from EU4. But I'm not sure.

Your vessel is in territory it shouldn't be (in EU4 this usually happened when a war ended) and thus is exiled, forcing it to return to your territory and making it impossible for it to interact with anything until it does.

An exiled fleet can only be directed to a system in your territory, so you could try to send it home on a different route or to another system in your space.

Is there any special symbol associated with the fleet in the outliner? I cannot see anything unusual on the fleets tag.

Comment: Can you comment on what FTL mode the ship has? The path it picks depends on that. Also, I'm assuming that you got kicked out of the system because that nation closed it's borders to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After mashing on buttons for a while, I figured out a way to do this, though it wasn't intuitive, and for all I know might not have worked until I was already out of their system of control.

Rather than hitting "Stop" or trying to tell it to Survey the system it was in, I instead needed to issue a new "Move" order. The new "Move" order overwrote the command to send it home.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on your ship there's a mode toggle for what to do if you encounter enemies. I don't have the game in front of me ATM but you can toggle between 'Evade' and 'Passive' I believe.

'Evade' will automatically have your ship bail out of the system. 'Passive' will enable them to do their surveying but at the risk of being attacked.

I'll update this when I get back home later with finer detail.

Comment: This has been important for [not having them flee a system when encountering hostile aliens](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/265217/3062), but did not prevent them from getting kicked out of the borders of a friendly nation.