# "There is no route" to neighboring uninhabited planet

Tags: stellaris

I have a science vessel at the edge of my territory, and I wish for it to explore a neighboring system which is seemingly uninhabited. However, when I try to move the ship I get a "There is no route for the selected fleet to reach this system."

I've googled around and found many similar cases, but all have to do with being trapped by an FTL inhibitor or trying to pass through another civilization's territory without being at war with them. As far as I can tell, however, this system is uninhabited, as was the system I'm departing from before I built my starbase.

[image]

Thinking this might be a border with a civilization I haven't discovered yet and my sensors haven't picked up (if that's even possible at this range), I also set the ship's stance to Passive, but still no dice.

So, what's going on here?

Comment: You are almost certainly right, it is mot likely another civilization that has closed borders with you.

Comment: @Yasskier can a civ close borders with a civ before meeting them? And wouldn't this be the moment we meet?

Comment: Yes they can have all borders closed by default (you can also change such settings). However, I am unsure what actually triggers the first contact. Also check are you giving order to explore the system or just move there - IIRC you cannot move to the unexplored system and "survey" and "move" are different commands.

Comment: @Yasskier: the "error" appears on mouse hover, before I even try to perform either action.

Comment: The error you see is also given when you try to visit a hostile system with "evasive" active. And your science ship is set by default to "evasive" (and I seem to recognize the icon on the top right of the group of six icons, but it has been some time since I last played the game). You might try to make sure your ship is set to "passive" and try again. (but I don't know why the game thinks the system is hostile if you have never visited it)

Comment: Similar question, but I don't think it's a duplicate: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/265217/2634 Seems to be a bit outdated as well, 4 years old.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Yeah, I tried that, no change.

Comment: Can combat ships enter the system?